# LLC in NY State but living and conducting business in Florida only

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, self-employment, state-income-tax

I am a software development consultant working as a self employed with a single member LLC incorporated in NY State.

During 2019 I had moved from NY State to Florida and am serving only one client which is located in Florida.

Do I need to pay NY State taxes for the the time I lived in Florida in 2019? What about 2020?

Are there any actions I can take to have strong ties to Florida besides having a driver license?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact a tax pro in NY that can help you with this.  NY state is very good at collecting taxes that are due and go to the extent to examine travel records for those that work part time in NY and in another state.  Attempts at cheating them had lead to tales of woe.  They are very good at catching tax cheats.

The money spent will be well worth the cost including if the advice is to form a new LLC outside of NY state.

If you are unwilling do do that, you may just want to form an new LLC outside of NY and use it to business.

Comment: "form a new LLC outside of NY state." This is a negligible amount. There's always the question, why would you want to send your taxes to a state you don't live in, where you have no hope of benefiting and cannot use virtually all of the public resources?

Comment: To add another complexity here - I am also receiving a W2 from a NY based employer - but once again - I don't even go to NY to visit that employer - does that make my case harder?

Comment: @Yos yes it does and makes more of a case for contacting a good tax person that is familiar with NY.